# Кастомный EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Столкнулся с проблемой кастомизации нижней полосы EditText. Нужно чтобы на каждый введенный символ была отведена отдельная полоса(см. рис.) [image: Пример EditText]

Реализовал путем помещения EditText и ImageView в RelativeLayout и отделив пробелами подставлял введенные символы.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_code"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@null"                                   
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="1px"

                        android:alpha="0.3"
                        android:background="@color/black" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="1px"
                        android:alpha="0.3"
                        android:background="@color/black" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="1px"
                        android:alpha="0.3"
                        android:background="@color/black" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="1px"
                        android:alpha="0.3"
                        android:background="@color/black" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Решение более чем плохое, возможно кто сталкивался с подобным злом?

Comment: я делал при помощи нескольких `EditText`

Comment: metalurgus, а как тогда вводить текст не переключаясь между ними?

Comment: при вводе символа переводить фокус на следующее поле. С удалением сложнее, но все возможно

Comment: Самое адекватное, это сделать отдельные EditText, но если сильно хочется, то никто не мешает переопределить EditText и реализовать в нём то, что вы описали выше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как насчёт использования уже готовых решений?

Кажется, [здесь](https://github.com/glomadrian/material-code-input) как раз то, что Вам нужно, в стиле Material Design.

Ещё один вариант, [тут](https://github.com/Philio/PinEntryView). На скриншотах по умолчанию немножко не так, как Вы хотите, но судя по описанию на гитхабе, есть большие возможности по кастомизации.

При этом в обоих вариантах нет проблем с переключением фокуса при вводе.

Comment: Хорошие решения, спасибо!