# Как в EditText сделать UI как в WhatSapp или в HH.ru

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я имею ввиду EditText куда вводиться цифры пароля от смс.

Чтобы было как на картинке в виде черточек - .

А когда вводишь они заполняются цифрами....

### ОШИБКА

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.eranewgames.medicina, PID: 10935
                                                                      java.lang.StackOverflowError
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:914)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:914)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:914)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:914)
                                                                          at android.view.View.addFocusables(View.java:6711)
                                                                          at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:92)
                                                                          at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:65)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:681)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:683)
                                                                          at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:6617)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:5717)
                                                                          at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1121)
                                                                          at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput(InputMethodManager.java:1071)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3733)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
                                                                          at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
                                                                          at com.eranewgames.medicina.Auth.LoginSmsCode$2.onTextChanged(LoginSmsCode.java:56)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
                                                                          at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
                                                                          at com.eranewgames.medicina.Auth.LoginSmsCode$2.onTextChanged(LoginSmsCode.java:57)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
                                                                          at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
                                                                          at com.eranewgames.medicina.Auth.LoginSmsCode$2.onTextChanged(LoginSmsCode.java:57)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
                                                                          at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
                                                                          at com.eranewgames.medicina.Auth.LoginSmsCode$2.onTextChanged(LoginSmsCode.java:57)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
                                                                          at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
                                                                          at com.eranewgames.medicina.Auth.LoginSmsCode$2.onTextChanged(LoginSmsCode.java:57)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
                                                                          at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
                                                                          at com.eranewgames.medicina.Auth.LoginSmsCode$2.onTextChanged(LoginSmsCode.java:57)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
                                                                          at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
                                                                          at com.eranewgames.medicina.Auth.LoginSmsCode$2.onTextChanged(LoginSmsCode.java:57)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7408)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3816)
                                                                          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
                                                                          at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextV
```

Answer (score 0):

первый вариант, прозрачный `EditText` поверх `TextView`, и когда вы вводите текст в `EditText`, он перехватывает текст, после чего вы его обрабатываете и сетаете в `TextView`.

второй вариант, заполнить `EditText` "- - - - -", после этого надо поставить слушателя на вводимый текст и его обрабатывать и пересетовать в `EditText`

**пример**

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                   //например у вас 9 символов в EditText изначально
                   if(editText.getText().length() == 10){
                      //тут обрабатываем текст и сетаем опять 9 символов 
                   }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }

            });
```

Comment: Можно пример второго? я пробывал через Watcher но у меня ошибка всегда вываливалась stackoverlow и типо нельзя по время слушания менять  EdtiText

Comment: добавил пример.

Comment: Добавил ошибку выше. Про что я и гвоорли вам

Comment: у вас рекурсия, надо от нее избавиться и все

Answer (score 0):

[Похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471500/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-edittext-android/576696#576696) уже задавался. В ответе есть ссылки на готовые библиотеки, которые реализуют необходимый Вам UI элемент

Comment: Это не то. Цифры должны перекрывать тире.
А там они снизу. Гляньте на картинку выше

Answer (score 0):

Эта штука *"как в Whatsapp"* называется **Passcode** - по имени виджета в iOS/iPhone.

В Android есть много реализаций [смотрите сюда](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=passcode%20android)